# node wants to use the "Local Items" keychain

Tags: keychain

Every so often when I open my computer, that message appears. Can anyone tell me what node is?

Comment: only when you wake it up from sleep ?

Comment: this might be trcky to do, but Open Console (inUtility folder), now watch your clock down to a second and remember when you open the lid. Go back to console find that time stamp and copy some 50 lines from it and paste in your post.

Answer (score 7):

I got this too, and I ran "ps aux | grep node" from the terminal. I've seen a couple of different programs show up. One was Videostream. Another was actually Adobe Creative Cloud:

kenlu              693   0.0  0.2  5996836  27612   ??  S    11Dec18  23:09.26 /Applications/Utilities/Adobe Creative Cloud Experience/CCXProcess/CCXProcess.app/Contents/MacOS/../libs/node /Applications/Utilities/Adobe Creative Cloud Experience/CCXProcess/CCXProcess.app/Contents/MacOS/../js/main.js

So it looks like this is just part of Adobe Creative Cloud, which is probably fine.

Comment: Edit: Added Adobe Creative Cloud as a possible cause.

Answer (score -1):

Most probably it caused by Adobe Creative Cloud, and make sure it this option,

1- check in system preferences>security and privacy>in the privacy tap make sure iCloud check marked.

2-system preferences >security and privacy >in general tap click open anyway the adobe creative cloud if showing here.

3-open finder> then click on "Go" type this command ~/library then press go>find keychain folder open it and delete all files, empty trash and restart your Mac

4-remove adobe creative cloud from start up, open system preferences>user and groups>clicl on login tap> select adobe if showing then remove it by clicking - button.